# Deploy site via ssh in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ee

I use gitlab.com on the free offer to do my CI. All my tests pass all good, now I want to deploy my app on a server at the end of the job. So I modified my .gitlab-ci.yml and I have a problem of keys through SSH.

Here is my gitlb-ci, I removed all the tests from it to make it clear.:

```yaml
stages:
  - deploy

image: python:latest

cache:
  paths:
  - ~/.cache/pip/


before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts


deployment:
  stage: deploy
  environment: 
    name: production
    url: manta.example.com
  script:
    - ssh user@example.com "ssh git@gitlab.com"
```

But when I launch it I have this error:

> Host key verification failed.

What did I do already:

- Checked the keys, the seems good
- I did a git pull directly from the server, it works well so it seems my server has access (out of the CI)
- The ssh connection works, if I replace the "ssh git@gitlab.com" with a touch file the file is well on my server
- directly on the server the ssh git@gitlab.com works well

So what I understand is that my CI connect in SSH but when it tries to connect to the gitlab server the key ... disapeared? I don't really know.

Comment: So you can connect from CI to your server but you cannot execute some command via ssh. But when you connect to server outside of CI, you can successfully execute the same command? Are you connecting with the same user from CI and when you test server manually? Test it with `ssh user@example.com  whoami` vs `ssh reallyTheSameUser(?)@example.com whoami`.

Comment: Mmmh ok problem fixed I just didn't copy the public key in the authorized keys on the server ... I hate myself :D